# Syntax highlighting errors in PhpStorm 7.1

Tags: ember.js, phpstorm, ecmascript-harmony, ember-app-kit

I got syntax highlighting errors in PhhpStorm when using the EcmaScript6 (harmony version) module syntax.

When I use this code (to be sure its not a fault): https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit-todos/blob/master/app/models/todo.js

Then I get the following errors in my editor:

[image]

I have enabled Ecmascript Harmony for the Javascript syntax highlighting in the settings.

Edit: see here a second example using an import call:

[image: Second Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 modules are still unsupported, vote for the issue on JetBrains bug tracker.

[Support Harmony modules](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7714)

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using SublimeText because the syntax is supported by them.

Comment: Can you guys tell what inspection should be turned off NOT to see these warnings ?